# My nested IF statements wont proceed in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, if-statement

Hi I am trying to use Excel to Determine the different"classes" that paints can fall in, summarised by the amount of time they dry. These statements are compared against different variables (e.g. If the time is greater than or equal to the mean, then it is “Standard”.) The problem is that the statement below doesn't seem to be getting entered by the search criteria, and so therefore only ever returning a "low cost" value as that is the first value in the statement.

```
=IF(G13>=TimeSummary!B21,"Low Cost",IF(G13>=TimeSummary!B20,"Budget",IF(G13>=TimeSummary!B17,"Standard",IF(G13>=TimeSummary!B23,"Premium","Exclusive"))))
```

Comment: Try putting all the symbols as `<=` instead of `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, G13 contains the value you are trying to use to determine one of 'Low Cost', 'Budget', 'Standard', 'Premium' or 'Exclusive'.

The first `IF`checks whether this value is larger than the value in sheet TimeSummary. If reads: if value is larger or equal to reference in TimeSummary, it's a low cost value.

Somehow, it doesn't sound right. I suggest you use:

```
=IF(G13<=TimeSummary!B21,"Low Cost",IF(G13<=TimeSummary!B20,"Budget",IF(G13<=TimeSummary!B17,"Standard",IF(G13<=TimeSummary!B23,"Premium","Exclusive"))))
```

It would also have been simpler with a vlookup, if the reference values were one after the other and not seemingly scattered about as your formula suggests.